# Ubercart - moving uc_order-customer.tpl.php to my theme folder makes emails sent twice

Tags: theming, ubercart, emails

Ive copied uc_order.tpl.php to my them folder as well as uc_order-customer.tpl.php which ive used to remove a few fields from the customer's notification email.

The problem is that now the same email notification is being sent twice at the same time, to the same email address.

If I remove the files from the theme folder, the problem goes away, but of course I need to modify the template and i wont want to hack core.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to the latest module version fixed this.